# Node.js - Get used memory of executed app (even after it has been killed)

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory

How can I take memory usage of `ChildProcess` even after it was killed (in `exec` callback)?

I tried using the `pidusage` module, but it only works when the process is opened.

What I actually tried:

```
var proc = exec(execComm,(error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        callback({status: -1, reason:stderr });
    }

    var pidusage = require("pidusage");

    pidusage(proc.pid,function(err,stat){
        console.log(err,stat);
    });

    callback({ status:0, file: out });
});
```

But why does pidusage send `[Error: No maching pid found]`?
Is it because this module can't get info of the already closed one?
And how to get that info in the `exec` callback?

Comment: You've extra `)` in callback.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind a helper to the exit signal of your app and read out memory usage then but since the gc will likely run on unpredictable times I'm not sure what use you get out of that.

```
const ExitHandler = () => { /* your code */ };
process.on( 'exit', ExitHandler.bind( null, { withoutSpace: false } ) );              // on closing
process.on( 'SIGINT', ExitHandler.bind( null, { withoutSpace: true } ) );             // on [ctrl] + [c]
process.on( 'uncaughtException', ExitHandler.bind( null, { withoutSpace: false } ) ); // on uncaught exceptions
```

Comment: A little explanation for what I'm doing: I'm want to create program which can test some outer code with templates... But program need to check:   
1.Is app has time overflow? (limited time maked with `setTimeout`)  
2.Is app has memory overflow? (which i trying to do now)  
so thats why i need to check: _how many memory is used?_

Answer (score 0):

I belive you could use something like [node-heapdump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heapdump) to create heapdumps in your child-processes that you could inspect after the fact.

That way you could also have multiple dumps so you could inspect the memory usage over time.